# 3 extra quotes (""") at start & end of payload once it is inserted into Elastic search index from FluentD

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

we are pushing data from our app server to FluentD and same is forwarded to Elastic Search index.
At FluentD we see the data is appropriate as :

```
{"message":"{\"foo\":\"abc\"}"}
```

But it reaches Elastic Search as  :

```
"message" : """{"foo":"abc"}"""
```

What might be the possible cause for the same? Should we be applying `any settings in ES or FluentD`?

Comment: You probably see those 3 double quotes in Kibana, right? See this: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/15628

Comment: If that's the case, it means that fluentd doesn't parse your JSON data and simply sends it as a string

Comment: @val - Thats right, i see this issue in kibana. can we do something at fluentd so that this can be fixed?

Comment: You need to configure fluentd to parse your input as JSON and not send it as text

Comment: Val - i tried json parser [link] (https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/json) with below configuration:
`code`
<match xxxx.logs>
  @type elasticsearch
  index_name aaaaa
  <parse>
    @type oj
  </parse>
</match>
`code`
And the quotes are still seen. Am I missing anything here??

Comment: @Val - any thoughts on above comment??